# How to retrive all subscription by user id in chargebee

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

Hello Every one I have a website developed in wordpress and Integrated Chargebee Wordpress plugin. Now i want to list all subscription by userid
I have already used this code to retrieve all details by userid

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();    
require 'ChargeBee.php';
$retrieve_result = ChargeBee_Subscription::retrieve($current_user->ID);
```